# can network layers communicate between each other?

Tags: communication-protocols

in a network architecture can two layers in different machines communicate between each other using some protocols, without having to go through the layers below, if yes how briefly ?

Comment: You should probably wait a little while before accepting an answer. Maybe somebody will come along and say the exact opposite of what I said!

Comment: Let’s side-step "can?" and give a resounding NO to "should?". Even if you could, it would be A Bad Thing. There are very good reasons for having equivalent functionality on the same layers at each side of  a network interface. I assume that you are well aware of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model and are just speculating here. Otherwise - bad programmer! BAAAD programmer!! No pizza!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Ultimately, for two computers to communicate, something physical (such as a bunch of electrons or photons) must pass between them and that's the lowest possible level of the OSI model.

In general, though, you shouldn't view the layers too rigidly. They're a vocabulary for talking about networking, rather than a requirement for writing network protocols.

Comment: I suppose that what is possible is for a layer to skip the hierarchy and talk several levels below on the same machine. But I doubt it is recommended.

Comment: @babou It's actually pretty common: very little goes on at layers 5 and 6 in TCP/IP, for example, so the application layer (7) tends to talk directly to the transport layer (4).

Comment: but generally on the same machine & OP is asking about different machines (and, personally, I would still make them speak through the intervening layers, even if they only provide a pipeline)